# project contain async method with Task.Run can I call it inside asp.net core 6 async action

Tags: asp.net-core

if i have a class library project contain a method that do long time calculation  ex:

```
async task<Array> Calculation()
{
 return await Task.Run(()=> some calculation that take time);
}
```

after that i used this methode inside asp.net core 6 action ex:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCalculation()
{
    var calc= await Calculation();
     return Ok(calc);
}
```

the question is this safe to be used like this ; because I have read some article to not use **Task.Run** inside asp.net core async action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you *can* do this. It's safe, and it will work.

However, it's not very *efficient*. That is why people generally discourage `Task.Run` in ASP.NET. What ends up happening is the request comes in, ASP.NET grabs a thread from the thread pool to handle the request, then the request calls `Task.Run` which schedules additional work to the thread pool and returns the request thread to the thread pool. Another thread pool thread then picks up the `Task.Run` work and does it.

So it works, but it adds unnecessary thread switching and puts more pressure on the thread pool in general. If you need to do it here and there, fine, whatever, but I wouldn't recommend it as a consistent pattern.

If the library has a synchronous API, that would be better than using the one implemented with `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thanks for your response; ok what is the purpose of asp.net  async action if i can use sync methods with sync asp.net action without any problem

Comment: Async methods on ASP.NET allow you to have a request not use *any threads at all* during a truly asynchronous operation, thus increasing the scalability of your server.